# Gmaps4Rails v2 remove and add event handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I using `gmaps4rails` `v2` in my app. I have multiple markers which I send in as a hash. I want to clear the default info window and use a different function on click and hover for each marker. This is what I found from other questions on this site, but it isn't working for me.

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);

for (var marker in markers) {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'click');
}
```

The other answers on this site mixed code from `v1` and `v2` of `gmaps4rails`.

Comment: Try: google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it didn't work. I have it located in the 'handler.buildmap({function(){*}})' in my partial view. Is this the right place for it?

Comment: yes could you show me your entire code?

Comment: `<script>
handler = Gmaps.build("Google", { markers: { clusterer: undefined  } });
handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
    },
    internal: {
      id: 'map'
    }
  },
  function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    for (var marker in markers) {
      google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
  }
);
<% content_for :scripts do %>
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {

  for (var marker in markers) {
      google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
  }
} 
<% end %>
</script>`

Comment: I had some provider options and also a kml added, but I don't think they are relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
```

It works fine, see live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Eci6H6NQWUvbkAvcDdc?p=preview

Infowindows dont appear anymore on click.